# How to use SED to remove texts starting from the first pattern until the second occurrence of the end pattern?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to use `sed` to remove texts starting from the line with the first pattern until the line with the second occurrence of the end pattern.

For example, the first pattern is `BEGIN`, and the end pattern is `BREAKPOINT`.

Input Example:

```
qq
ww
BEGIN
ab
ef
BREAKPOINT
ij
mn
BREAKPOINT
kk
BREAKPOINT
zz
yy
xx
BEGIN
ab
ef
BREAKPOINT
ij
mn
BREAKPOINT
pp
```

Expected Output:

```
qq
ww
kk
BREAKPOINT
zz
yy
xx
pp
```

Could you please kindly tell me how, or maybe an alternative way to achieve this?

PS. I know only how to show texts between the first pattern until the second occurrence of the end pattern, but I do not know how to remove them.

```
sed -n '/BEGIN/{:a;N;s/BREAKPOINT/&/2p;Ta}' file
```

Thanks.

Comment: sed is the best tool for doing `s/old/new/` on simple strings but if you're using sed language constructs other than s, g, and p (with -n) then there are better tools available that will provide some combination of clearer, simpler, more efficient, more portable, and easier to maintain solutions.

Comment: What should happen if there's only 1 BEGIN and 1 BREAKPOINT in the input?

Answer (score 3):

It's almost certainly not impossible to do this in `sed`, but also almost certainly somewhere between hard and impossible to understand the solution some weeks from now unless you are extremely familiar with `sed`. Better then to switch to a more human-readable scripting language:

```
awk '/^BEGIN$/ && !s { s=2 }
!s
/^BREAKPOINT$/ && s { s-- }' file
```

In very brief, the variable `s` keeps track of whether we have seen  the beginning separator and if so how many times we want to see the terminating separator before reverting to printing the input lines.

Comment: very smart and elegant solution, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples only, please try following `awk` code, written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
/^BEGIN/,/^BREAKPOINT/{
  flag=1
  next
}
flag && /BREAKPOINT/{
  flag=""
  next
}
!flag
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                     ##Starting awk program from here.
/^BEGIN/,/^BREAKPOINT/{   ##Checking range from line starts from BEGIN till line starts BREAKPOINT then do following.
  flag=1                  ##Setting flag to 1 here.
  next                    ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
flag && /BREAKPOINT/{     ##Checking condition if flag is SET and BREAKPOINT is found then do following.
  flag=""                 ##Nullifying flag here.
  next                    ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
!flag                     ##Checking condition if flag is NULL then print current line.
' Input_file              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

A perl:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/^BEGIN[\s\S]*?^BREAKPOINT[\s\S]*?^BREAKPOINT\R//gm' file
```

Or,

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/^BEGIN(?:[\s\S]*?^BREAKPOINT\R){2}//gm' file
```